# Interpolate SVG Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

So I've been trying to create a long shadow effect in Inkscape using an SVG image. As you can see, I've been able to do this with a shape.

[image]

But haven't found a way to do so with an SVG image.

[image]

What I'd normally do is select both paths and choose Extensions>Generate from path>Interpolate, but of course, in my experience, this requires a path. I've tried various ways to convert the image to a path, but have thus far been unsuccessful.

So my questions are:
Is there a way to create a long shadow effect without a path?
If not, is there a way to convert the SVG image to a path?

All I should need is an outline of the image.

Comment: A sort of [motion blur](http://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/shadows-blurs-and-other-useful-filters-in-inkscape--vector-23219)? I'm sorry, perhaps it's my browser configuration, but I'm not able to see the first image (I see it black!).

Comment: Ok, I see it now. Mmm... for a complex object like the Tardis have you tried to create a copy of it, [outline](http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=7586) it (if vector) or [trace](https://inkscape.org/doc/tracing/tutorial-tracing.html) it (if an image) and use the obtained contour to generate the shadow?

Comment: @PaoloGibellini Thank you for your reply. The TARDIS is a SVG image, so I tried outlining it, but that seems to simply apply a black border to the image. Interpolating that would be fine, yet Extensions> Generate from path> Interpolate still does not work. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you upload the SVG file you're working with, in its simplest form?

Comment: @SeanMadsen Sure, I should have done that earlier. http://bit.ly/1wOApwl

Comment: Extension,,,Generate from path works on paths and not on groups, imho. I suggest you to try this: **duplicate** the Tardis with **Ctrl-D**, select just the duplicate, hit repeatedly **Shift-Ctrl-G** to **ungroup** all the nested groups until appears the message "No groups...". Hit **Ctrl-+** to make a **union** of the path: you have the outline of the Tardis. Now, the interpolatio should work.

Comment: Your image contains text, youn need an intermediate step of Path...Object to path, and again Shift-Ctrl-G

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After seeing your file, I can answer.

At first, **duplicate** the Tardis with **Ctrl-D**, then select just the duplicate, hit repeatedly **Shift-Ctrl-G** to **ungroup** all the nested groups until appears the message *"No groups to ungroup in the selection"*.

The groups contain text and other objects, so you have to use **Path...Object to path**, and again **Shift-Ctrl-G** until done.

[image: A lot of objects]

Hit **Ctrl-+** to make an **union** of the path: you have the outline of the Tardis:

[image: Union]

The union contains some undesired nodes, you have to edit it and remove them:

[image: Odd nodes]

Now, you can proceed to [interpolate](https://inkscape.org/doc/interpolate/tutorial-interpolate.en.html), by placing a copy of your outline:

[image: two paths to interpolate]

And using *"Extensions...Generate from path...Interpolate"*:

[image: interpolated image]

I've used 100 steps but I don't like the result (but I don't use often the interpolate tool and perhaps it can be tweaked a bit), so I've made a test with *"Extensions...Generate from path...Motion"* with a Magnitute of 1000,0 (seems to be the maximum), and (after some ungroup and an union of the result) I prefer this way better:

[image: with the motion is better]

The [motion](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Extensions-GenerateFromPath.html#Extensions-Motion) uses less nodes, and I suggest you to give a look to this function.

For a longer *shadow* you can duplicate the result of the motion and place it conveniently:

[image: final image]

Comment: Personally, i would use Extensions > Generate From Path > Extrude. And use the "Polygons" mode in that, and just union all the resulting shapes the extension produces. This results in less jaggy edges (and nodes).

Comment: Indeed, the extrusion is another way.